# How to resolve the JSON. Stringify() method overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frontend

```
document.write(JSON.stringify(6448223430062899470));
```

I get the output of `6448223430062899000`, how to solve the JSON. Stringify overflow, thank you

Comment: why are you using JSON.stringify on a plain number. Answers can be given only if the question makes sense.

Comment: @Nirus, "why" doesn't matter, it is a legal operation. "The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string," from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: my intention is to display this large integer on the page, and the direct output back causes the overflow, which needs to be converted to string and then rendered to the page.

Comment: @Paul Are you sure that works?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate - the "existing question" isn't the same and the accepted answer isn't really an answer. I nominate to reopen this question.

Comment: @Paul I tested it, and it's overflowing for ' ' + 6448223430062899470

Comment: @Paul my question was a rhetoric question: it doesn't work, `6448223430062899470` is not `6448223430062899000`. Besides that, this question is clearly a duplicate, and the problem is exactly the same of the linked question. Of course you can vote to reopen it, this community is a democracy.

Comment: Yeah, my initial answer was incorrect. Coffee hasn't kicked in yet. This question is a "how", the other question is a "why". The answer is it can't be done - he needs to change the data type from number or break his number into two parts. Or find some library to do it for him.